# SDL 2.0 on Mac - how to activate/respond to greyed-out Toggle Full Screen menu item?

Tags: macos, menubar, sdl-2

Working on porting a Windows game to Mac using SDL2, and I noticed on the Mac that the menu bar for the game includes a View menu with an item Toggle Full Screen.  I'm assuming SDL put it there automatically, as I didn't request it anywhere in my code.  However, since the game can run in a window or full screen (and the window is resizable), I figure I should make this menu item actually work somehow.

I know practically nothing about Mac OSX coding (I just followed a tutorial to get my SDL app to build on the Mac side in XCode), and I can't find anything in the SDL documentation about how to respond to, activate, or remove this menu item (or other ones that are greyed out, like the Minimize option in the Window menu).  Best I could find online is a reference to it being added in a commit to the SDL code base, but nothing in the commit message about how one is supposed to hook it up to their application code.

So, how do I activate and respond to this menu item (and any other menu items that only show up in OSX builds for that matter, like Minimize and About)?  And is it something I can hook up in a cross-platform way via SDL itself, or did SDL add something that I have to deal with using platform-specific OSX code?

Comment: I haven't used SDL since 1.x; does it still provide an `SDLMain.m` to do the Mac-specific stuff? Or is that all hidden away now?

Comment: If it does I'm not sure how to hook that in, the app works fine and there's no SDLMain.m or SDLMain.h anywhere in my project.  Was it necessary in SDL 1.x or optional?

Comment: It was necessary for 1.x and came as part of the Xcode template; it had all the application delegate stuff in it so you could add ten lines to receive a UI event from the OS then push it onward as an SDL event into the platform-neutral stuff. I'll see whether I can find an opportunity to see what 2.0 does...